# cant make a validation to mongoose schema with nestjs-joi lib

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, joi

i am trying to use joi validation with mongoose schema in nestjs but there is an error i couldn't solve it
and here is my code
schema.dto.ts

```
import Joi from "joi"
import { JoiSchema, JoiSchemaOptions } from "nestjs-joi" 

@JoiSchemaOptions({
    allowUnknown: false,
  })
export class EmployeesJoi {
    @JoiSchema(Joi.string().required())fullName!: string;
  }
```

and here a small demo for my controller

```
    @Post('AddNew') 
       async add(@Body() employee: EmployeesJoi ) {

           await console.log(employee)

        }
}
```

and finally, I faced that error

nest start

H:\000\training-center\dist\employees\dto\employees.dto.js:21
nestjs_joi_1.JoiSchema(joi_1.default.string().required()),
^

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\000\training-center\dist\employees\dto\employees.dto.js:21:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\000\training-center\dist\employees\employees.controller.js:18:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `joi`'s exports are named exports, so you need to do

```js
import * as Joi from 'joi';
```

instead of

```js
import Joi from 'joi';
```